# Ler arquivo de uma pasta e determinar se é igual ao do site

Tags: c#, .net

Estou fazendo um launcher autoupdate em c# .net e preciso que meu programa leia um arquivo database que esteja na mesma pasta que ele e veja se é igual ao do meu site, e se for diferente, ele fazer o download.

Alguém sabe se isso é possível?

Comment: É possível sim, uma das saídas é utilizar conexão FTP

Comment: Qual é o db? você quer comparar a estrutura ou o conteúdo também?

Comment: Sua pergunta deixa uma dúvida, o que é exatamente esse "arquivo database"? É um arquivo de banco de dados, um `Access` por exemplo?

Comment: É uma database de um jogo que estou fazendo. Mas eu já consegui com o método de md5 do Rovann Linhalis, muito obrigado a todos que tentaram ajudar!! Sou muito grato mesmo ^^

Answer (score 1):

**Na aplicação local você pega o md5 do arquivo que você precisa:**

```
public static string Md5FromFile(string input)
{
    string saida = null;
    using (System.Security.Cryptography.MD5 md5Hasher = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create())
    {
        Byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(input);
        Byte[] data = md5Hasher.ComputeHash(bytes);
        StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var valorByte in data)
            sBuilder.Append(valorByte.ToString("x2"));

        saida = sBuilder.ToString();
    }
    return saida.ToString();
}
```

**e o Md5 do arquivo que está no site:**

```
public string GetMd5FromSite(string arquivo)
{
    NameValueCollection nvc;
    nvc = new NameValueCollection();
    nvc.Add("arquivo", arquivo);
    System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
    string URL = "http://www.seudominio.com.br/pasta/md5.php";
    WebProxy myProxy = new WebProxy();
    myProxy.BypassProxyOnLocal = true;
    client.Proxy = myProxy;
    byte[] responseArray = client.UploadValues(URL, nvc);
    return new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding().GetString(responseArray);
}
```

***md5.php***

```
<?php
function fmd5($p_arquivo)
{
    return md5_file($p_arquivo);
}

echo fmd5($_POST['arquivo']);
?>
```

**Utilização:**

```
 string md5Local = Md5FromFile(Application.StartupPath+"\\arquivo.txt");
 string md5Site = GetMd5FromSite("arquivo.txt"); //considerando que o arquivo está no mesmo diretório do md5.php

 if (md5Local != md5Site)
 {
     //faz o download
 }
```

---

> Como meu servidor trabalha com php, utilizei este recurso como exemplo. Seguindo a mesma lógica você também utilizar outra linguagem.

---

> Este exemplo funciona para um arquivo. Se forem vários arquivos, a lógica é a mesma, porém o `md5.php` é diferente para que, em apenas uma request sejam retornados todos os md5 de uma pasta informada. Caso contrário o servidor poderá bloquear sua conexão pelas quantidades seguidas de requisições.

Comment: Consegui com o seu método, funcionou exatamente como eu queria. Você praticamente fez o trabalho todo sozinho, desculpa kkkk Muito obrigado mesmo!! Nem sei como agradecer ^^

Comment: @Murdock rsrs, marque como resposta =] por nada!