# Aplicação WinForms para de funcionar se o computador entra em hibernação

Tags: c#, hibernate, windows

Tenho uma aplicação em `winforms`, que fica no servidor da empresa, então puxo o atalho para a área do trabalho e o colaborador executa normalmente.

O problema começou a acontecer, quando trocamos alguns computadores (Desktop) por notebook's, quando o notebook entra em hibernação, ao voltar a aplicação para de funcionar.

No momento, faço uma solução paliativa, que detecto quando o windows está para entrar em hibernação e finalizo a aplicação, mas não é bem certo isso..

Alguem teria outra alternativa? ou poderia me dar alguma dica?

Comment: `app.exe` versão 1 funcionando, notebook hiberna, você atualiza a aplicação no servidor (versao 2), vc "acorda" o notebook com a aplicação já aberta. Qual versão deveria funcionar ? Quando hiberna perde conexão, quando voltar já não existe sessão / conexão com o servidor, vai parar mesmo. Eu prefiro manter os executáveis no computador cliente...

Comment: @RovannLinhalis a versão é a mesma, não é atualizado.. posso manter a versão no computador, porém, ira precisar elaborar, um processo para verificar a versão, se estiver desatualizado, precisaria montar um processo de atualização.. Tenho alguns métodos que salvam arquivos, iria precisar refaze-los para salvar o arquivo em um caminho da rede.. e isso que eu quero evitar..

Comment: o exemplo de versão foi só para demonstrar o que pode acontecer... o computador hiberna, você pode apagar o arquivo do servidor, quando ele voltar não tem como funcionar mesmo. Desabilitar a hibernação é uma opção (ótimo, ao meu ver não traz vantagem nenhuma, computador fica lerdo depois, etc) e se precisar de fazer atualização, veja essa resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/277495/69359

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer com que sua aplicação não permita que o windows hiberne enquanto estiver aberta. Algo assim:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    private uint m_previousExecutionState;

    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Set new state to prevent system sleep (note: still allows screen saver)
        m_previousExecutionState = NativeMethods.SetThreadExecutionState(
            NativeMethods.ES_CONTINUOUS | NativeMethods.ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED);
        if (0 == m_previousExecutionState)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Call to SetThreadExecutionState failed unexpectedly.",
                Title, MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            // No way to recover; fail gracefully
            Close();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnClosed(System.EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnClosed(e);

        // Restore previous state
        if (0 == NativeMethods.SetThreadExecutionState(m_previousExecutionState))
        {
            // No way to recover; already exiting
        }
    }
}

internal static class NativeMethods
{
    // Import SetThreadExecutionState Win32 API and necessary flags
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern uint SetThreadExecutionState(uint esFlags);
    public const uint ES_CONTINUOUS = 0x80000000;
    public const uint ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED = 0x00000001;
}
```

Comment: Boa ideia, vou tentar essa solução e aviso sobre. Obrigado