# Alterações em um aplicativo Desktop - Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Estou começando a criar aplicações do tipo desktop no Visual Studio C# e me veio a seguinte dúvida, após gerar um executável da aplicação e instalar em um outro computador é possível fazer alterações nessa aplicação sem ter que desinstalar o que já esta em funcionamento? Como se fosse um "pacote de atualização". Se existe como, alguém poderia me dizer ou postar algum link ou fontes que posso procurar sobre o assunto. Desde já agradeço a quem puder ajudar.

Atenciosamente,

Comment: Você se refere a uma aplicação Windows Forms, WPF ou UWP?

Comment: não está muito claro o que você precisa. Veja se te ajuda: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/277495/69359

Comment: @LeandroAngelo, a princípio aplicação Windows Form.

Comment: @Q.Wesley Agora falta você incluir na sua pergunta: Como é feita a instalação e que tipo de atualização você pretende fazer

Comment: @RovannLinhalis, é mais ou menos assim, se eu gero uma aplicação que possui uma tela simples e depois eu gostaria de mudar algo nessa tela (o nome dela por exemplo), eu teria que gerar todo um executável para reinstalar a aplicação na máquina do usuário ou se tem um meio de apenas fazer um upgrade, passado um arquivo que contenha as alterações. Vou olhar os links que você postou, obrigado.

Comment: você terá que enviar os arquivos compilados de novo... o link que coloquei é uma opção pra atualizar esses arquivos no cliente, mas, será um pouco mais complicado =]

Comment: @LeandroAngelo, vou fazer essas alterações na pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o nuget AutoUpdater.NET, com este nuget atraves da versao do assembly que voce modificar nas propriedades do projeto ou no arquivo AssemblyInfo nos campos:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

o github de como utilizar o nuget é: https://github.com/ravibpatel/AutoUpdater.NET

e para instalação você pode utilizar o programa inno setup, ele é bem intuitivo, esse programa vai gerar um executável que faz a instalação do seu sistema.